# How can i get a callback on successful sharing on facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Lets say, I have a bot game which offers a user to share the result screen with other users of messenger. For this reason messenger has a 'Share' button. When user clicks on Share Button Facebook offers to choose which users to share with.

The question is how to get a callback if users successfully shared the screen with at least one user.

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: @WizKid, I would like to give a bonus to user if he shared the app.

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. So if you don't want your app deleted you shouldn't do it

Comment: @WizKid, virtual bonus for sharing is not allowed?

Comment: You are not allowed to incentivize them in any way. It is extremely clear in the Facebook Platform Policy. https://developers.facebook.com/policy if you haven't read it

Comment: @WizKid, thank you for letting me know, just read it.

Comment: What if you just wanted to track how often users engage with an app that is shared directly with them vs via other channels?

Comment: Then have the user share a unique link that includes a parameter that you know the URL was shared. And then when others click on that URL you know it came from sharing

Comment: That doesn't give you engagement rate, only # of engagements. To get the engagement rate, you need (# of engagements) / (# of shares)

Comment: Correct. Because you can't get number of shares